# Function plotting library for java

Tags: java, math, graph, eps

I need to plot a 2 argument function (so I need a 3D plot) - ideally Mathematica style with nice colours for different values, which I will then use in a Latex document. I would prefer to get a vector output (i.e. EPS), so that it prints nicely. Please note that I will not display it on the screen (my app runs as a batch job).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used both [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/index.html) and [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). I have very positive experience using JFreeChart, especially with what you described here. You can do whole lot of customizations, like tweaking colors, gradients, etc. I *believe* it handles vector output, but don't quote me on that. :)